# Validar que una clave tenga al menos una @ y una letra mayúscula

Tags: python, string, validación

Estoy realizando un ejercicio en Python que consiste en pedir al usuario una clave en la que sí o sí tenga que tener una "@" o una letra mayúscula.

El programa es algo así, llevo una semana programando...

```
clave=input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

caracter=False

for i in range(len(clave)):
    if clave=="@" and clave==#Aquí es donde no sé exactamente qué poner para que esa condición se cumplapy
        caracter=True

if clave==True:
    print("La clave es valida")
else:
    print("La clave es incorrecta")
```

Comment: Puedes sacar el valor número del caracter y comprobar si se encuentra en el rango de los caracteres en mayúscula de la [tabla ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unas cuantas observaciones:

- La idea es iterar sobre cada carácter y comprobar si cumple una de las condiciones. Ahora iteras tantas veces como caracteres tiene la variable clave, pero no iteras sobre los caracteres.
- Si iteras con:

  ```
  for i in range(len(clave))
  ```

  debes obtener cada carácter indizando:

  ```
  caracter = clave[i]
  ```

  de todas formas, en Python itera siempre directamente sobre el iterable con un `for in` si no necesitas modificar sus items, es más eficiente y más legible.

  ```
  for caracter in clave:
  ```
- En cada iteración debes comprobar si el carácter es una @ **o** (`or`) es una letra mayúscula, no si son ambas cosas (`and`).
- Para comprobar si un carácter es una letra mayúscula o no puedes usar el método `str.isupper()`
- Por eficiencia, combine que rompas el ciclo en cuanto encuentres una @ o una mayúscula. Para ello puedes usar `break`.

---

```
clave = input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

caracter_presente = False

for caracter in clave:
    if caracter == "@" or caracter.isupper():
        caracter_presente = True
        break

if caracter_presente:
    print("La clave es válida")
else:
    print("La clave es incorrecta")
```

Realmente no necesitas la variable boleana, puedes valerte de la cláusula `else` junto a un `for`:

```
clave = input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

for caracter in clave:
    if caracter == "@" or caracter.isupper():
        print("La clave es válida")
        break
else:
    print("La clave es incorrecta")
```

El contenido del `else` solo se ejecuta **si el `for`  iteró al completo sobre el iterable**, es decir, si no se ejecutó el `break`.

Especificas que la clave debe tener "una "@" **o** una letra mayúscula". Si la condición fuera "una "@" **y** una letra mayúscula", entonces si necesitarás tener dos variables boleanas, una implementación con una sola iteración y también con cortocircuito puede ser:

```
clave = input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

arroba_presente = False
mayuscula_presente = False

for caracter in clave:
    if caracter == "@":
        arroba_presente = True
        if mayuscula_presente:
            print("La clave es válida")
            break
    elif caracter.isupper():
        mayuscula_presente = True
        if arroba_presente:
            print("La clave es válida")
            break
else:
    print("La clave es incorrecta")
```

Comment: correo=input("Por favor, introduce un correo por pantalla: ")
arroba_presente=False
punto_presente=False

for caracter in correo:
 if arroba_presente=="@":
  arroba_presente=True
  if arroba_presente:
   print("El correo es valido")
   break
 elif punto_presente==".":
  punto_presente=True
  if punto_presente:
   print("El correo electronico es valido")
   break
else:
 print("El correo electronico no es valido")

Answer (score 3):

Como otra alternativa más a las muy buenas respuestas anteriores, mis "two cents":

```
def pwd_correcta(pwd):
    if '@' in pwd and pwd.lower() != pwd:
        return True
    return False

clave = input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

if pwd_correcta(clave):
    print('Cumple requisitos')
else:
    print('No cumple con los requisitos')
```

- **Para ver si incluye una arroba:** `'@' in pwd`, esto da `True` si existe el caracter en el string.
- **Para ver si incluye una mayúscula:** `pwd.lower() != pwd`, esto da `True` si la contraseña NO es lo mismo que la contraseña en minúsculas (es decir, tiene mayúsculas).

Answer (score 1):

La idea que llevas puede funcionar con revisar si el carácter mayuscula, pero para eso deberías de tener dos dos variables de tipo booleano, algo así como:

- caracter1 = False
- caracter2 = False

Ahora bien, resulta que python nos brinda herramientas que nos pueden ayudar a simplificar ciertos algoritmos, el siguiente código debería de ser suficiente para validar la clave:

```
clave=input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")

caracter=True if '@' in clave and any(letra.isupper() for letra in clave)
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejercicio se resuelve de forma simple utilizando Regex(Expresiones regulares);en python solo tienes que declararla de forma.

```
import re
```

y contiene distintos métodos que puedes usar:

```
re.findall(busco esto,en esto)  Returns a list containing all matches
re.search(busco esto,en esto)   Returns a Match object if there is a match anywhere in the string
re.split(busco esto,en esto)    Returns a list where the string has been split at each match
re.sub(busco esto,en esto)      Replaces one or many matches with a string
```

Te comparto:

[Documentacion oficial de python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

[Herramienta oficial para regex online](https://regex101.com/)

Solucion:

```
#se cumple siempre y cuando la cadena este formada por solo letras
import re

 x = str(input("Introduce tu cadena: "))

if(re.search("[a-z][A-Z{1}|@{1}]",x)is not None): 
        print("validación correcta")
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer uso de la función istitle, la cual comprueba si la primera letra de una palabra es mayúscula. En tu caso, al ser un char, te valdría: 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_istitle.asp

Además, en python para iterar caracter a caracter sobre un String, no es necesario obtener su tamaño, como en otros lenguajes. 
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

```
clave=input("Por favor, introduce la clave: ")
caracter=False

for i in clave:
    if i=="@" or i.istitle():
        caracter=True

if caracter==True:
    print("La clave es valida")
else:
    print("La clave es incorrecta")
```

Comment: nunca dijo que solo la primera podia ser mayuscula...

Comment: Antes de comentar y puntuar, por favor, lee y entiende sobre lo que lo estas haciendo.

En ninguna parte del código, se compara si solo la primera letra es mayúscula, ya que la función istitle se aplica caracter a caracter y no en la frase entera, por lo que si comprobamos si un único caracter empieza por mayúscula, quiere decir que el propio caracter lo es.

Comment: Los votos no son publicos.. antes de acusar a alguien que voto de tal o cual manera, ten por seguro si es de quien te voto. De cualquier manera, tu solucion fallaria para hOla.. ya que istitle devolveria falso segun la documentacion, y esa clave si tiene una mayuscula. es mas, para la clave HOLA tambien devuelve falso... por favor, verifica eso, que esta en la misma documentacion que pasaste.

Comment: Ahora, entiendo lo que decis que usas la funcion solo con un caracter.. pero entonces, por favor, deja eso en claro en la respuesta...